# Simulating a camera flash

Tags: after-effects

Can anyone give me some tips on simulating a camera flash in After Effects. I am trying to make it keyframing the scale and opacity of a white shape layer but I can't get it to look right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a photographer, a flash is simply a very short burst of white light (as you're no doubt aware). The maximum time at full power is usually around 1/250th of a second, which is equal to 1/10th of a frame. In that case, if you were to accurately represent a flash being fired, you would simply boost the exposure of a single frame by several stops (to make it almost completely white, whilst retaining a little bit of detail).

Something as simple as this would suffice.

[image]

For one frame.

[image]

If you really wanted to be technically accurate, you could simulate the CMOS flicker of a flash by only boosting the exposure on a horizontal portion of the frame, say the top 2/3rds or something.

Comment: So, we've given him two different answers. One that simulates a subject getting hit by a flash, and one that simulates a flash firing into the camera.

Answer (score 2):

In After Effects, there is an effect `Exposure` that controls the exposure of the layer. You could probably use that instead of a white shape layer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that you've filmed a flash that you want to "fire" in After Effects.
If you buy the Video Copilot **Optical Flares** or Red Giant **Knoll Light Factory** you can simply put a lens flare on the flash and animate the strength.

Download a trial and see for yourself!